# How to check if a button is disabled using css in selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

I need some help on checking if the button is disabled , attaching the screen shot of dom for reference, tried `isEnabled()` function from `WebDriver`, but it's returning true.

[image: Need to check if this button is disabled]

Answer (score 1):

You can check if the element has `disabled` attribute. If it exists you will get `String` results, if not you will get `null`

```
WebElement button = driver.findElement(locator);
bool isDisabled = button.getAttribute("disabled") != null;
```

Answer (score 1):

There are two way to check if the *button* is **disabled** as follows:

- Using `try-catch{}`:

  ```
  try {
      //css
      driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("fieldset.checkbox button.calvary-button[disabled]"));
      //xpath
      //driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='calvary-button' and contains(.,'Continue')][@disabled]"));
      System.out.println("Button is disabled");
  } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
      System.out.println("Button is enabled");
  }
  ```
- Using `findElements()` and and assert zero length response:

  ```
  if(driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("fieldset.checkbox button.calvary-button[disabled]")).size()>0)
      System.out.println("Button is disabled");
  else
      System.out.println("Button is enabled");
  ```

Comment: This checks if the button exists, not if it disabled.

Comment: Exactly, if the button exists along with the _attribute_ **disabled** e.g. `[disabled]`. Sysouts are configurable.